# Converting IF statement to VBA with Variables

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to convert the following IF statement into text that will be filled into a cell through VBA:

```
=IF(XLOOKUP(N7,'EDL Filter'!R2:R660,'EDL Filter'!AA2:AA660)="YES","Port Specific",XLOOKUP(N7,'EDL Filter'!R2:R660,'EDL Filter'!AB2:AB660) )
```

I've tried splitting it up as I have with other Xlookup statements below:

```
ActiveCell = "=IF(XLookUp(N" & SafetyRow2 & ",'EDL Filter'!R2:R660,'EDL Filter'!AA2:AA660)=""Yes"",""Port Specific"", Xlookup(N" & SafetyRow2 & ",'EDL Filter'!AB2:AB660))"
```

However, I keep getting Run-time Error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

The variables have been defined and used earlier in my code without issue, but I am still new to VBA so I might be missing something obvious.

Comment: Try `Debug.Print "=IF(XLookUp(N" & SafetyRow2 & ",'EDL Filter'!R2:R660,'EDL Filter'!AA2:AA660)=""Yes"",""Port Specific"", Xlookup(N" & SafetyRow2 & ",'EDL Filter'!AB2:AB660))"` and see if the output looks like what you expect.  And maybe use `ActiveCell.Formula` to assign the formula.

Comment: `XLOOKUP` needs at least 3 arguments yet you have provided only 2 for your second one i.e. `'EDL Filter'!R2:R660` is missing as its 2nd argument.